# Pegar índices com chaves iguais de um array não associativo

Tags: php, array, foreach, array-multidimensional

Como faço para pegar/agrupar os índices com chaves iguais de um array, exemplo:

```
Array
(
    [field_label] => Array
        (
            [0] => Texto
            [1] => Checkbox
            [2] => URL
        )

    [field_type] => Array
        (
            [0] => text
            [1] => checkbox
            [2] => url
        )

    [field_value] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => valor_1 | Valor 1
valor_2 | Valor 2
            [2] => 
        )

    [field_required] => Array
        (
            [0] => on
            [1] => on
            [2] => on
        )

    [field_order] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
        )

)
```

Eu quero que o array fique da seguinte forma:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=5)
      'field_label' => string 'Texto' (length=5)
      'field_type' => string 'text' (length=4)
      'field_value' => string '' (length=0)
      'field_required' => string 'on' (length=2)
      'field_order' => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => 
    array (size=5)
      'field_label' => string 'Checkbox' (length=8)
      'field_type' => string 'checkbox' (length=8)
      'field_value' => string 'valor_1 | Valor 1 valor_2 | Valor 2 | valor_3 | Valor 3' (length=55)
      'field_required' => string 'on' (length=2)
      'field_order' => string '2' (length=1)
  2 => 
    array (size=5)
      'field_label' => string 'URL' (length=3)
      'field_type' => string 'url' (length=3)
      'field_value' => string '' (length=0)
      'field_required' => string '' (length=0)
      'field_order' => string '3' (length=1)
```

Comment: Você poderia colocar o resultado em código para ajudar né? =)

Comment: Vou colocar....

Comment: E coloque o resultado final esperado

Comment: Coloquei mais informações... Veja se melhorou.

Comment: Ficou boa a pergunta.

Comment: Acredito que minha resposta está certa. Mas faça o teste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim:

**EDIÇÃO**

O problema era que o seu array está dentro de um outro array. Então tive que alterar o código para isso:

```
$newArray = [];

$maxKeys = count(max($array[0])); // conta o número máximo de chaves internas do array

for($x = 0; $x < $maxKeys; $x++){
    foreach ($array[0] as $key => $arr){
        if(isset($arr[$x])){
            $newArray[$x][$key] = $arr[$x];
        } else {
            $newArray[$x][$key] = "";
        }

    }
}

print_r($newArray);
```

[Veja funcionando](https://ideone.com/GFJtZ9)

Comment: A sua saída ficou como eu preciso, porém lá no primeiro bloco de código que eu passei os índices podem ir além de [0,1, 2]. Testando o seu script quando eu passo o meu array, ele não funciona. Onde é pra ficar [field_*] => value acaba retornando 0 => ''

Comment: Estou fazendo alguns testes aqui com o seu código, mas acredito que o problema esteja com o for.

Comment: @RodrigoFontes Calma ae... Vou arrumar.

Comment: @RodrigoFontes veja agora como ficou

Comment: @RodrigoFontes Altera o `$array` pelo nome da sua variável

Comment: Nossa, a sua solução funcionou :D Bem diferente do que eu estava tentando fazer.

Comment: @RodrigoFontes que bom que deu certo! =)